# Why does the pivot-function in SQL Server output multiple rows of data, if a distinct value in non-pivoted data is present?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm trying to Pivot a table.
Can somebody explain me why this works as expected (results in one row of data):

```
-- This is what I would expect to get 
;WITH My_Data AS 
(
    SELECT  
        '4A8C72D8-F02A-44E4-8E5A-23451CB436B1' AS ENTRY_UID  
        ,'Entry 1' AS ENTRY_Lang_DE
        ,'' AS ENTRY_Lang_EN

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT  
        '5688ABC1-D2C5-4FE7-9E0A-6195CFF0563E' AS ENTRY_UID  
        ,'Entry 2' AS ENTRY_Lang_DE
        ,NULL AS ENTRY_Lang_EN
)
-- SELECT * FROM My_Data 


    SELECT
        MAX(CASE WHEN ENTRY_UID = '4A8C72D8-F02A-44E4-8E5A-23451CB436B1' THEN ENTRY_Lang_DE END) AS [4A8C72D8-F02A-44E4-8E5A-23451CB436B1],
        MAX(CASE WHEN ENTRY_UID = '5688ABC1-D2C5-4FE7-9E0A-6195CFF0563E' THEN ENTRY_Lang_DE END) AS [5688ABC1-D2C5-4FE7-9E0A-6195CFF0563E]
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT
             ENTRY_UID,
             ENTRY_Lang_DE
            ,ENTRY_Lang_EN
        FROM My_Data 
        -- WHERE ENTRY_UID <> '5688ABC1-D2C5-4FE7-9E0A-6195CFF0563E'
        -- WHERE ENTRY_UID = '5688ABC1-D2C5-4FE7-9E0A-6195CFF0563E'
        -- ORDER BY ENTRY_Lang_DE
    ) AS T_My_Data 
    ;
```

But the query below using the pivot-keyword creates two rows, one with NULL values, and another that is the correct output... 
Why? 
I mean obviously it's because ENTRY_Lang_EN is NULL and not string.empty, but why? 
It creates one entry for every distinct ENTRY_Lang_EN? 
ENTRY_Lang_EN is not subject to the pivotization process, why does it do that? 
As one can see with the above query, the result is clearly not equal...

```
-- This is what PIVOT actually does ... 
;WITH My_Data AS 
(
    SELECT  
        '4A8C72D8-F02A-44E4-8E5A-23451CB436B1' AS ENTRY_UID  
        ,'Entry 1' AS ENTRY_Lang_DE
        ,'' AS ENTRY_Lang_EN

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT  
        '5688ABC1-D2C5-4FE7-9E0A-6195CFF0563E' AS ENTRY_UID  
        ,'Entry 2' AS ENTRY_Lang_DE
        ,NULL AS ENTRY_Lang_EN
)
-- SELECT * FROM My_Data 

SELECT pvt.* FROM My_Data 

PIVOT 
( 
    MAX( ENTRY_Lang_DE ) 
    FOR ENTRY_UID IN 
    ( 
         [4A8C72D8-F02A-44E4-8E5A-23451CB436B1] 
        ,[5688ABC1-D2C5-4FE7-9E0A-6195CFF0563E]
    ) 
) AS pvt
```

Somehow it must be grouping on other fields, right?

I would imagine something along the lines of

```
-- This is what it would do if it would group 
;WITH My_Data AS 
(
    SELECT  
        '4A8C72D8-F02A-44E4-8E5A-23451CB436B1' AS ENTRY_UID  
        ,'Entry 1' AS ENTRY_Lang_DE
        ,'' AS ENTRY_Lang_EN

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT  
        '5688ABC1-D2C5-4FE7-9E0A-6195CFF0563E' AS ENTRY_UID  
        ,'Entry 2' AS ENTRY_Lang_DE
        ,'a' AS ENTRY_Lang_EN
)
SELECT
     CASE WHEN ENTRY_UID = '4A8C72D8-F02A-44E4-8E5A-23451CB436B1' THEN MAX(ENTRY_Lang_DE) END AS A
    ,CASE WHEN ENTRY_UID = '5688ABC1-D2C5-4FE7-9E0A-6195CFF0563E' THEN MAX(ENTRY_Lang_DE) END AS B 
FROM My_Data
GROUP BY ENTRY_UID
;
```

Except that it groups by all fields? 
But if that is so, then why does it not output a row for every UID?

What exactly does the pivot-command do behind the scenes? 
Or in other words, what would be the required SQL without using the pivot command (aka group by with case and max) to get to this strange result?

Comment: Which question are you looking for an answer on? You have asked several different things in here.

Comment: I think it's very clear what the pivot does. It groups all the columns involved in your query except the one that is inside the pivot operator "thing". If you look closely, ENTRY_Lang_EN is part of the pivot output so it's also grouped on. Please do yourself a favor and don't use PIVOT operator because it's just a poor man's conditional aggregation but without any flexibility

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help a lot.

Comment: @Charlieface: the sample-data is in the My_Data CTE. It's already dumbed down to the issue.

Comment: And what is the expected results?

Comment: All entries of LANG_DE in one ROW (with the alias being the column_name). 
That way, reportserver can get ranslations with table.row[0]["here the column name"] and gets translations.

Comment: You have to remove the unnecessary columns by doing a subquery: `SELECT pvt.* FROM (select entry_uid, entry_lang_de from  My_Data ) x PIVOT ...`

Comment: @siggemannen: Yea that much is obvious. I'm just trying to figure out: WHY ?

Comment: Because pivot is just a syntaxic sugar for the final statement which is basically a GROUP BY all columns outside of AGG_FUNCTION call

Comment: *"Somehow it must be grouping on other fields, right ?"* You can see this in your results though; you have `Pvt.*`, which is `SELECT pvt.ENTRY_Lang_EN, pvt.[4A8C72D8-F02A-44E4-8E5A-23451CB436B1], pvt.[5688ABC1-D2C5-4FE7-9E0A-6195CFF0563E]`. In your query with conditional aggregation you have *two* columns; `pvt.ENTRY_Lang_EN` is omitted, and if you added it you would *have* to add it to the `GROUP BY` as it's not aggregated. If you did, you'd get the same result as your `PIVOT`. YOu can actually see, in your results, what columns `PIVOT` is grouping on.

Comment: @siggemannen: Regarding " It groups all the columns involved in your query except the one that is inside the pivot operator "thing"" - yes you are right - just noticed myselfs. Part two of the comment is also correct - better to not use this ...

Comment: @StefanSteiger yeah, this has bitten me a few times too many, so i don't use PIVOT except for the simplest of cases, plus, one can never remember the exact syntax :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, got it myselfs.
What it does is NOT grouping by the columns contained in the AGGREGATE **OR** the FOR clause selection-source, but by all other columns.

```
;WITH My_Data AS 
(
    SELECT  
        '4A8C72D8-F02A-44E4-8E5A-23451CB436B1' AS ENTRY_UID  
        ,'Entry 1' AS ENTRY_Lang_DE
        ,'' AS ENTRY_Lang_EN
        ,'' AS ENTRY_Lang_FR 

    UNION ALL 
    
    SELECT  
        '5688ABC1-D2C5-4FE7-9E0A-6195CFF0563E' AS ENTRY_UID  
        ,'Entry 2' AS ENTRY_Lang_DE
        ,NULL AS ENTRY_Lang_EN
        ,'' AS ENTRY_Lang_FR 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        '88908037-DB5A-4F43-ACAA-3863550A49B1' AS ENTRY_UID  
        ,'Entry 3' AS ENTRY_Lang_DE
        ,NULL AS ENTRY_Lang_EN
        ,'b' AS ENTRY_Lang_FR 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
         '00225A88-4EF1-46D2-819D-DC130FAFEFEC' AS ENTRY_UID 
        ,'Entry 4' AS ENTRY_Lang_DE 
        ,NULL AS ENTRY_Lang_EN 
        ,'a' AS ENTRY_Lang_FR 
)

SELECT 
     ENTRY_Lang_EN 
    ,ENTRY_Lang_FR 
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN ENTRY_UID = '4A8C72D8-F02A-44E4-8E5A-23451CB436B1' THEN ENTRY_Lang_DE END) AS [4A8C72D8-F02A-44E4-8E5A-23451CB436B1] 
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN ENTRY_UID = '5688ABC1-D2C5-4FE7-9E0A-6195CFF0563E' THEN ENTRY_Lang_DE END) AS [5688ABC1-D2C5-4FE7-9E0A-6195CFF0563E]
FROM My_Data
GROUP BY 
    -- do not group by ENTRY_UID or ENTRY_Lang_DE 
    ENTRY_Lang_EN, ENTRY_Lang_FR
```

is the equivalent of

```
;WITH My_Data AS 
(
    SELECT  
        '4A8C72D8-F02A-44E4-8E5A-23451CB436B1' AS ENTRY_UID  
        ,'Entry 1' AS ENTRY_Lang_DE
        ,'' AS ENTRY_Lang_EN
        ,'' AS ENTRY_Lang_FR 

    UNION ALL 
    
    SELECT  
        '5688ABC1-D2C5-4FE7-9E0A-6195CFF0563E' AS ENTRY_UID  
        ,'Entry 2' AS ENTRY_Lang_DE
        ,NULL AS ENTRY_Lang_EN
        ,'' AS ENTRY_Lang_FR 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        '88908037-DB5A-4F43-ACAA-3863550A49B1' AS ENTRY_UID  
        ,'Entry 3' AS ENTRY_Lang_DE
        ,NULL AS ENTRY_Lang_EN
        ,'b' AS ENTRY_Lang_FR 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
         '00225A88-4EF1-46D2-819D-DC130FAFEFEC' AS ENTRY_UID 
        ,'Entry 4' AS ENTRY_Lang_DE 
        ,NULL AS ENTRY_Lang_EN 
        ,'a' AS ENTRY_Lang_FR 
)
SELECT pvt.* FROM My_Data 

PIVOT 
( 
    MAX( ENTRY_Lang_DE ) 
    FOR ENTRY_UID IN 
    ( 
         [4A8C72D8-F02A-44E4-8E5A-23451CB436B1] 
        ,[5688ABC1-D2C5-4FE7-9E0A-6195CFF0563E]
    ) 
) AS pvt
```

Comment: Often it's easier to just write a manual pivot using `GROUP BY ()` and `MAX(CASE WHEN ENTRY_UID = '4A8C72D8-F02A-44E4-8E5A-23451CB436B1' THEN ENTRY_Lang_DE END)` etc it's also much more flexible as it allows you to pivot multiple columns together, and to add different types of aggregation.